# RabbitMQ Java channel "Closed due to exception from Consumer method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel" in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm trying to set up an amqp RabbitMQ consumer that is connected to a message queue from work. The code works just fine by itself, but as soon as I add it to my JavaFX application and open the channel, it closes with the message `Closed due to exception from Consumer method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel`. I've tried using the manual acknowledgement as some suggest, but without success. This is the code that I use to connect to the queue:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public final class QueueListener {
    private static QueueListener INSTANCE;

    public static QueueListener getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new QueueListener();
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void setInstance(QueueListener q){
        INSTANCE = q;
    }

    private MainController controller;

    private ConnectionFactory factory;
    private Connection conn;
    private Channel channel;

    private String queue;
    private String host;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void connect(String queue, String host, String username, String password) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.host = host;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setUsername(username);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setHost(host);

        Map<String, Object> qmode = new HashMap<>();
        qmode.put("x-queue-mode", "lazy");
        qmode.put("x-single-active-consumer", true);

        conn = factory.newConnection();
        channel = conn.createChannel();

        channel.addShutdownListener(cause -> System.out.println(cause.getReason()));

        boolean durable = true;
        channel.queueDeclare(queue, durable, false, false, qmode);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

            message = message.replaceAll("\\u000D", "");

            System.out.println(message);
            MyLogger.logger.info(message);
            controller.parseData(message);
        };
        boolean autoAck = true;
        channel.basicConsume(queue, autoAck, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {});
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        channel.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    public void setController(MainController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

The error was actually caused by the line `controller.parseData(message)`, when setting the controller I was creating another instance of the `MainController`, which was causing the error